# angular 6 combine two arrays if ID matches plus show all from the first array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

I have two arrays

```
schools = [{name: school 1, id: 1, address: 'address'}, {name: school 2, id: 2, address: 'address'}, {name: school 3, id: 3, address: 'address'}, {name: school 4, id: 4, address: 'address'}];

apply_status = [{user_name: 'name', school_id = 1, applied_status: pending }, {user_name: 'name', school_id = 2, applied_status: accepted}, {user_name: 'name', school_id = 4, applied_status: accepted},]
```

So far I have tried this

```
this.status = (this.schools, this.applyStatus) =>
    this.schools.map(itm =>
      ({
        ...this.applyStatus.find((item) =>
          (item.school_id === itm.id) && item), ...itm
      }));
```

this gives only two matching results. I would like to show the third school as well even if there is no Id to match.

My desired result:

```
status = [{name: school 1, id: 1, address: 'address', applied_status: pending}, {name: school 2, id: 2, address: 'address', applied_status: accepted}, {name: school 3, id: 3, address: 'address'}, {name: school 4, id: 4, address: 'address', applied_status: accepted}];
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Just tried your code and it is giving desired result. Are you sure that you are not modifying any of the three array anywhere ?

Comment: @SachinGupta I am not modifying the arrays. Somehow it is giving me only two results. thanks for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there. Simply reutrn the element with `undefined` (or whatever you want) as status, if there is no match inside the `applied_status` array:

```js
schools = [{name: 'school 1', id: 1, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 2', id: 2, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 3', id: 3, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 4', id: 4, address: 'address'}];

apply_status = [{user_name: 'name', school_id: 1, applied_status: 'pending' }, {user_name: 'name', school_id: 2, applied_status: 'accepted'}, {user_name: 'name', school_id: 4, applied_status: 'accepted'}];

const results = schools.map(school => {
  const applyStatus = apply_status.find(status => status.school_id === school.id);
  return {
    ...school,
    status: applyStatus ? applyStatus.applied_status : undefined
  };
});
console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the `applied_status` of the schools using `array#find` and then push the result depending on the value of the `applied_status` in an array.

```js
let schools = [{name: 'school 1', id: 1, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 2', id: 2, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 3', id: 3, address: 'address'}, {name: 'school 4', id: 4, address: 'address'}],
    apply_status = [{user_name: 'name', school_id: 1, applied_status: 'pending' }, {user_name: 'name', school_id: 2, applied_status: 'accepted'}, {user_name: 'name', school_id: 4, applied_status: 'accepted'}],
    status = schools.map(school => {
      let {applied_status} = apply_status.find(o => school.id === o.school_id) || {};
      return applied_status ? ({...school, status: applied_status}) : ({...school});
    });
console.log(status);
```

Answer (score 0):

So here is my way of doing this stuff:

```
 this.schools.forEach(item => {
      let status = this.applyStatus.find(x => x.school_id === item.id);
      if (status) {
        item['applied_status'] = status.applied_status;
      }
    });
```

check out this [stackbliz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53905871?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts) running code.